# SQL Find the number of orders in each line count

Tags: sql

I have a SQL question from one of the well known IT company couple month ago when they were interviewing me, and I never got it figured out.

An order can have multiple lines - For ex., if a customer ordered cookies,

chocolates, and bread, this would count as 3 lines in one order. The question

is to find the number of orders in each line count. The output of this query

would be something like 100 orders had 1 line, 70 orders had 2 lines, 30 had 3

lines, and so on. This table has two columns - order_id and line_id

```
 Sample Data:
 order_id   line_id
 1      cookies
 1      chocolates
 1      bread
 2      cookies
 2      bread
 3      chocolates
 3      cookies
 4      milk
```

**desired output:**

```
 orders line
 1       1
 2       2
 1       3
```

So generally speaking, we have a very large data set, and the line_id per order_id can be ranging from 1 to infinite(Theoretically speaking).

```
 The desired output for the general case is:

 orders line
 100    1
  70    2
  30    3
  etc..
```

How can I write a query to find the total number of orders per line count=1,2,3... etc

My thought on this problem is to first subquery the count of line_id per order_id.

And then select the subquery along with a list of values as the second column ranging from 1 to max(lines_id per order)

```
 Test Data:

 create table data
 (
 order_id int,
 line_id char(50)   
 );


 insert into data
 values(1,  'cookies'),
 (1,    'chocolates'),
 (1,    'bread'), 
 (2,    'bread'),
 (2,    'cookies'),
 (3,    'chocolates'),
 (3,    'cookies'),
 (4,    'milk');


 Since order_id=1 has 3 lines,
 order_id=2 has 2 lines,
 order_id=3 has 2 lines,
 order_id=4 has 1 line.

 Thus it yield our solution:

 orders line
 1       1
 2       2
 1       3

 This is because both order_id = 2 and 3 has 2 lines. So it would mean 2 orders has line = 2.
```

So far, I have:

```
 select lines,
 sum(case when orders_per_line = '1' then 1 else 0),
 sum(case when orders_per_line = '2' then 1 else 0),
 sum(case when orders_per_line = '3' then 1 else 0)
 from(
 select lines, order_id, count(*) as orders_per_line from data
 where lines in ('1, '2', '3')
 group by order_id, lines
 )
 group by lines
```

My query is wrong, as I only want 2 columns, and also creating a sequence of numbers ranging from 1 to max(lines per order) is also wrong.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the question is a bit vague, what do you mean with "to find the number of orders in each line count"?

Comment: It means, given a table of order_id and line_id. You first have to find the count(order_id), and then find how many count(order_id) has line = 1, =2,  =3.. etc! for example, if 10 order_id has count(order_id) = 1, 5 order_id has count(order_id)=2, and 3 order_id has count(order_id) =3. then the output is:  count(order_id), line ||  10, 1 || 5, 2 || 3, 3

Comment: If you don't know the difference between MySQL and SQL Server, you're not cut out for that job

Comment: @podiluska, I know you are good at SQL based on your reputation, but I honestly got stuck with this question. So if you were trying to humiliating me based on your knowledge, then I have nothing else to say. I didn't get that job because I wasn't ready back then.  Moreover, I use SQL Server at work but first learned MySQL. As a matter of fact, I only have MySQL installed on my PC. Lastly thank you for your input as well as voting me down.

Comment: @user1489597 The point is that SQL is platform specific. If you want generic SQL, don't use a specific tag, or you'll annoy multiple sets of different people.

Comment: @podiluska If you are one of the "people" being annoyed by the multiple tags, I have removed the rest and only leave the generic SQL on. However, you should have pointed it out in the first place and not being offensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select Count(*) as Orders, Lines from (
    Select order_id, Count(*) as Lines from data group by order_id
)query group by Lines
```

For exmaple, look at this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9904e/4)

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
with a AS
(
SELECT 
    COUNT(order_id) AS Orders
FROM
    Table_1
GROUP BY
    Order_Id    
) 
SELECT 
    Orders,
    COUNT(*) AS line
FROM 
    a
    GROUP BY Orders
```

Comment: Thanks user3815462, please read my question carefully! Your solution answers hwo to find the total numbers of line_id per order_id, and is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: i thought you asked: How can I write a query to find the total number of orders per line=1,2,3...

Comment: Maybe you can explaine how the Test Data (cookies, bread, etc..) should look like in the end

Comment: I have just modified the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot user3815462. I sincerely appreciate your time! your code works too! Sorry that I could only check mark on one solution.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it just count how many times the order_id are repeated:

`SELECT order_id, count(order_id) FROM data GROUP BY order_id`

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, the required solution is a bit more complex than just count(order_id), since we have to aggregate the count into a table where number of orders and line= 1,2,3,4,5,6,....